# DQN - How to feed the input of 4 still frames from a game as one single state input

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I was reading this blog about [Deep Q-Learning](http://deeplizard.com/learn/video/wrBUkpiRvCA).

1- In the `The input` section of the blog, I wanted to know how do we feed the 4 still-frames/screenshots from the game, that represent the input state, into the Policy network? Will all 4 frames be fed in one flattened tensor (where one image ends the next one starts, forming a continuous row input, in one tensor)? Or will they be fed separately one after the other into the network?

2- For preprocessing the images, do we avoid using the Max-pooling stage? My understanding is this process eliminate the need for spacial/position recognition in image-feature recognition. While in normal Conv-Net this is important for recognising image features regardless of where they appear in space and distance (so we us max-pooling). In Q-learning for games, the space/position of different elements on the image is important. Therefore, we remove the use of Max-pooling from the proprocessing stage. Is this correct?

3- Can anyone recommend a good implementation resource of Deep Q-learning, written from scratch (in Python), i.e. without the use of out-of-the-box libraries, like PyTorch, Keras and Scikit-learn ..etc, for a game, where image frame feeds from the game is required as states input. I'm thinking perhaps implementing the model from scratch gives a better control over customisation and fine tuning of the hyper-parameters. Or is it better to use out-out-of-the-box library? Any code implementation on this would be super helpful.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, the typical approach is to stack the (gray-scaled) frames, such that the input shape becomes `[height, width, num_frames]`, i.e. the frames take on the role that's usually reserved for the color channels in an RGB image. This makes it easy to apply 2D convolutions.
2. Yes, that is correct. You don't use pooling, because you don't want to throw away information about spatial location.
3. I would advice against this particular approach. I would suggest instead to familiarize yourself with all the building blocks of the function approximator (at least at the conceptual level). This might mean going back to mnist to study the components of CNNs. After that, you probably won't want to implement everything from scratch. Here's a blog post that I found pretty useful:

   - [Beat Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning! (Part 1: DQN)](https://becominghuman.ai/lets-build-an-atari-ai-part-1-dqn-df57e8ff3b26)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers Kris. Just to clarify and make sure I understood your answer to question 1. So we use the axis that's normally reserved for the color channels RGB, to become the number of frames. But since we're grey-scaling the image for CNN, so we won't need the RGB colors. Great that makes sense.

Comment: For question 3, I've read some articles about how CNN works. Yes you're right. Come to think of it, CNNs are much more complex than a simple ANN, so best to use libraries. Thank you so much for sharing the article. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You're very welcome! As to your first comment, yes, grayscaling collapses the channels to just one channel and stacking gives us multiple "channels" again.

Comment: What about if we have RGB frames? Do we still stack them at channel level to obtain `[height, width, 3 * num_frames]`?

Comment: @JosepJoestar Yes, that would be the easiest to implement. Another way might be to do the concatenation along the batch axis and then reshape after the convolutions.. The only added benefit that I can think of is that you might be able to reuse some pretrained convolution layers from a different task (transfer learning). But I would just concatenate in the channel axis as you suggest.